# Custom packaged CKEditor: Make buttons available on profle configuration page

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

We wanted buttons to add Definition Lists (dl, dt, dd tags) in CKEditor using this CKEditor plugin [ckeditor-plugin-descriptionlist](https://github.com/Reinmar/ckeditor-plugin-descriptionlist). There is already [ckeditor_descriptionlist](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_descriptionlist) module but not available for Drupal 7 at the moment.

So, we packaged CKEditor to have descriptionlist plugin in it. Here is that custom built CKEditor package: [ckeditor-4.5.11-full-with-descriptionlist.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpw8dutxv2xtsvn/ckeditor-4.5.11-full-with-descriptionlist.zip?dl=0).

Problem is that three buttons from descriptionlist plugin is not available in CKEdior profile configuration pages to add to any particular profile.

I know we can backport above mentioned ckeditor_descriptionlist module to work in Drupal 7. But I am asking whether it will be possible to bring that buttons for configuration without using a drupal module as we have CKEditor package with required plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

Earlier I was using "CKEditor 4 Presets Builder" available at https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets . That is not required. I just have to put copy of descriptionlist plugin within "plugins" directory of CKEditor library. Then those three buttons started to appear in CKEditor profile configuration page.